# What is the extrinsic curvature for the edges of a cube?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, curvature

Is it possible to define mean curvature around bend/kink e.g. edge of a cube?

I take piece of paper (X-Y plane ) and bend it along a line (Y axis) it by angle $\theta$. Since this bend can be seen as a *cylinder* with zero radius, I would naively think that mean curvature diverges. But then this implies that it doesn’t depend on $\theta$, which also seems bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: The mean curvature does indeed diverge. You can however define it as a measure supported along the crease. The magnitude of the measure does depend on the angle.

Comment: I may have a conceptual misunderstanding. Since $ 2 H=k_1+k_2, ~k_2= 0, ~ k_1$  infinite for all angles at the folds/ edges of a cube or prism, physically does not the scalar sum always diverge?

Comment: @Narasimham Your comment and answer are "classically" correct, but Deane's and Ted's comments seem to me more in the spirit of the question: There is a way we can assign "infinite mean curvature" (as with a delta function) to an edge of a polyhedron in such a way that the angle between faces is recovered by a _two-dimensional_ integral whose integrand is non-zero only on a _one-dimensional_ edge (a measure supported along the crease, as Deane puts it). <> It would be valuable for someone (probably not me) to write up this story for posterity....

Comment: @ Okay, thanks for your comment. ( I am still scratching my head on differentiability /continuum / manifold ). I seek a bit of your indulgence/ time to look at quite another practical consideration, with another intrinsic dimension to the question.. (that I mention still seeming to miss the point !).

Comment: Take a sheet of A4 paper and squeeze it together making as small a ball as possible. Then straighten out the paper back  to be flat again forming a plane... When  carefully observed,  we are left with  *two* types of permanent crease discontinuities: 1) Edge or Straight line Folds considered in OP's question & $ k1=0,k2\to \infty$ 2)  *Toroidal* type, $ k2=0,k1\to \infty.$. Now the plethora of all such discontinuities must be seen to be so accommodative..